# Delphi - TIdAttachment, remove path from file name of attachment

Tags: delphi, indy, email-attachments

I am generating emails with attachments thru a Delphi program using Indy 10 and TIdAttachment.  The file location/name is stored in a database table as //server/files/attachments/MyAttachment.pdf.  I am attaching the file to the email as follows:

```
   // Add each attachment in Attachments
    for Attachment in Attachments do begin
      // Make sure file name exists before trying to add
     if FileExists(Attachment) then
       TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MessageParts, Attachment);
    end;
```

When I send the email the file attached is named

`'__server_files_attachments_MyAttachment.pdf'`.

Is there a way to remove the file path so the attachment appears as 'MyAttachment.pdf' when the recipient receives the email?

I tried using ExtractFileName() but no luck.  I don't think it works as the path & file name are coming from the database as one string.

**EDIT**

I also tried to extract the file name itself as follows:

```
function GetFileName(FullPath: string): string;
var
   StrFound: TStringList;
begin
    StrFound := TStringList.Create();
    ExtractStrings(['/'], [' '], PChar(FullPath), StrFound);
    result := StrFound[StrFound.Count - 1];
end;
```

This returns 'MyAttachment.pdf' but this results in Delphi looking in the folder in which the program is running for the file not in '//server/files/attachments'.  It appears that unless I can rename the attachment after calling TIdAttachmentFile.Create() I cannot change the file name.

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

Showing the solution using Remy's comments (and using `GetFileName()` from above):

```
// Add each attachment in Attachments
for Attachment in Attachments do begin
  // Make sure file name exists before trying to add
  if FileExists(Attachment) then begin
     with TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MessageParts, Attachment) do begin
       Filename := GetFileName(Attachment);
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Exactly what did you pass to `ExtractFileName`?

Comment: I called ExtractFileName(attachment);  where 'attachment' is '//server/files/attachments/MyAttachment.pdf'

Comment: It's better if you post the solution at the bottom of Remy's accepted answer. Question is just for... question. Feel free to edit someone else posts, SO is a place to share knowledge ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows may recognize `'/'` as a path delimiter, but the RTL does not. Local paths and UNC paths alike must use `'\'` instead.  You will have to normalize your filename string from `'/'` to `'\'` before passing it to Indy, such as with `UnixPathToDosPath()`.

Comment: I think you don't have to do this. It should be possible to just set a separate file name for the attachment, that shouldn't even be the same as the original file name. Your solution is a work-around for a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: You can always set the `TIdAttachment.FileName` property separately to whatever you want after constructing the attachment object instance.  The `TIdAttachment` constructor uses `ExtractFileName()` to set a default property value, but you are not locked in to that value if you do not want it.

Comment: While changing '/' to '\' worked to get the filename, Delphi now only sees 'MyAttachment.pdf' and doesn't attach the file.  I was able to solve this however using the TIdAttachment.FileName property (see original post, second edit for solution).  Thanks Remy!

Comment: `TIdAttachmentFile` maintain separate `FileName` and `StoredPathName` properties.  The `StoredPathName` property contains the full path and filename, and is used to manage the underlying file.  The `FileName` property contains just the filename by itself for display and reporting purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the TIdAttachmentFile with only the filename you want the attachment to have. After construction, set the StoredPathName property of the attachment to the full path.

```
var
  a: TIdAttachmentFile;
  FileName: string;

...

  FileName := ExtractFilePath(AttachmentPath);
  a := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MessageParts, FileName);
  a.StoredPathName := AttachmentPath;
```

Comment: Do it the other way around.  Let the constructor set the `StoredPathName` property and then update the `FileName` property to what you want it to say.

Comment: That may be true. I might have misinterpreted the code, and wasn't able to test it at the moment. Thanks for the addition/correction.

Answer (score 0):

The call to TIdAttachment.Create includes its own ExtractFilename call, so you don't need to call it ahead of time - it needs that path to find your files.

I think you're in a catch-22, you need to send the TidAttachment.Create a path that it understands because it uses the full path to add your file, then it extracts just the filename for you as you want to include in your message.  I don't think it's working like you want because it can't perform the ExtractFilename part appropriately.  So, rather than extract the filename, just form the path in a way the the TIdAttachment.Create can understand.

In this case, I'd try mapping a drive, and use the drive mapping as:

Z:\files\attachments\MyAttachment.pdf = //server/files/attachments/MyAttachment.pdf

Just pre-process your attachments replacing //server with Z:\ and / with \ then try it.

Edited to consider Remy's comment:
Swap / chars to \ chars

\\server\files\attachments\myattachment.pdf

Then make the call to TIdAttachment.Create

Comment: Indy can use a UNC path just fine.  The problem is in the `'/'` characters.  They need to be `'\'` instead.